# In GitHub's graphing metrics, what are 'additions'?

Tags: github, code-metrics

Are they lines of code added, or are they something else?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

They are line of code added or modified. They are the lines marked with a `+` when you do a `git diff`

Comment: So, is this a reliable means of judging how many lines of code are in a project (this is, additions - deletions)?

Comment: Hum no, but that's a good way of judging the impact of a commit in a project (if the end-of-line markers haven't been converted between Windows-Unix machines).